# Angular ContentChildren Access and Manipulation

Tags: angular

I have a component that will use `ng-content` to pass in a list of elements that will be output on the screen. I want to use ng-content so that the parent component, the one that implements the list, can determine the styles of the list elements. It will look something like this when implemented:

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<list-component>
    <li #result *ngFor="result of results$ | async"> { result.title } </li>
</list-component>
```

And the List component class:

```
<!-- list.component.ts -->
export class ListComponent {
    @ContentChildren('result') results: QueryList<ElementRef>;
}
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.results.changes.subscribe((changes: any) => console.log(changes))
}
```

The changes are logged to the console, but as soon as I add the reference variable `#result` to the `li` elements in `app.component.html`, the content on the `li` no longer shows. It shows one bullet point for each of the `li` elements still, but the `result.title` no longer shows.

Why is that? What can I do to make those show up?

My end goal is to have the `ListComponent` use the `ContentChildren` variable and loop over the elements and bold a search term in that `li` element. So if the search term is 'test', and the results are 'contest', 'testing', etc. then the 'test' part of each word would be bolded and the non-matching parts would stay normal. I want the `ListComponent` to handle that part.

Is this the proper way to do that?

Comment: It could be because of `result` being defined two times within your template. Change `#result` to something else.

Comment: So, it almost certainly is, but if I don't put the template variable `#result` on there, then the `this.results.changes` no longer works. I've also tried `@ContentChildren(ElementRef)` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I meant you change it to something like `#results`

Comment: I didn't think it would affect it at all, making it plural like that, but it worked. If you'd like to submit an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Okay, just submitted an answer with more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s because you have two `result` defined in `<li ...` scope. One from template variable `#result`, one from `*ngFor=“let result of results”`. You should change it to something unique like `#resultTemplate` so it would not overlap any variable of the component.